# Creating and claiming a test venue to use with Foursquare Merchant Platform

Tags: foursquare

Is it possible to create and claim test venues to use with the API?  I've created two venues (which are not real businesses), and I'd like to claim them as the venue manager so I can test as I build with the API.

Comment: Were you able to claim any test venue ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to claim a venue via the API. You can e-mail api@foursquare.com with the fake venue ID & requested manager ID and we can set it up for you.

Comment: Since this is an old post, I just want to confirm if above answer is still valid for claiming a test venue ?