# Claim a Venue API endpoint

Tags: foursquare

I'm curious about Claim a Venue API endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/claim).
It states that only venue manager can use it, so I get "not authorized to claim via api" 403 error.

Question is, isn't the /claim endpoint usage is precisely getting venue manager rights over the venue? If not, for what it used for?

I did a little search and old topics says that venue manager rights requires verification via phone, card or an e-mail, but they also stated that there is no /claim API method at all, so I figured they a bit outdated?

[How to claim venue using Venues & Venues Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695028/how-to-claim-venue-using-venues-venues-platform)

[Creating and claiming a test venue to use with Foursquare Merchant Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609360/creating-and-claiming-a-test-venue-to-use-with-foursquare-merchant-platform)

[Does foursquare provide any test accounts for developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820679/does-foursquare-provide-any-test-accounts-for-developers/8827424#8827424)

Backstory is that I have an application that search through existing venues of our business at Foursquare and add venues which is not there yet. I'm using /add endpoint with OAuth token which do not grant me venue manager rights (so, added venues not displayed at my profile pages), and I'm looking for a way to automatize this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for venues/claim](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/claim) states that this endpoint only works if your key has proper privileges:

> **If your OAuth Consumer is set up with the proper privileges**, you can
>   use this endpoint to claim a venue on behalf of a user without the
>   claim having to be approved by foursquare staff.

You can try [contacting Foursquare](https://enterprise.foursquare.com/contact-us) if you think this may apply to your app.

Comment: Yeah, I read that part :) But what is a "proper privileges"? As I see it, I need to be a venue manager to claim a venue, and I need to claim a venue to become a venue manager - so, vicious circle?

Thats why I'm asking, may be I figured out requirements and usage all wrong for this endpoint.

Comment: enc_life, as I stated in backstory, I'm looking for a more automatic approach, that is why I'm curious about this particular endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/claim). It is there, right at the docs page, and it looks more promising than a verification through phone, card or mail, so I'm trying to gather as much info as I can about this endpoint and its use-cases before moving to other methods :)

Comment: There are obvious reasons why Foursquare can't open this endpoint up publicly. If you feel like programatic venue claiming is the best approach for your app you should contact Foursquare and see if you can get approved.